# Dispatch work to multiple queue's and wait synchronically

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I want the test below to pass. In my real code, `AsyncClass` is dispatching work to multiple queue's using the `DispatchGroup` class. In Swift we work with `@escaping` completion handlers for async work. I am looking for a way to make the calling thread wait for the `dispatchGroup` to finish working. The closure could go away that way.

So long story short: I have a calling thread (main) that is calling a function that is dispatching work to multiple queue's. I want the calling thread to be blocked while that work is going on and be unblocked when the work is done. This results in that the @escaping completionHandler can go away and I can call the function normally without a closure (and when I go to the next line after the method call, the work is completely done ofcourse)

I use this code only for tests, I know I should never block the main thread in production.

Usecase: I have tests which call an expensive method. That method is doing work like ‘AsyncClass’ in this example. Inside AsyncClass I am dispatching work to some threads to speed things up. Now while testing, I can create expectations all the time and call this method with a closure, but that’s to verbose for me. I want to turn an async method to a sync method, for the ease of use.

```
import XCTest

class DispatchGroupTestTests: XCTestCase {

    func testIets() {
        let clazz = AsyncClass()

        var isCalled = false

        clazz.doSomething {
            isCalled = true
        }

        XCTAssert(isCalled)
    }

}

class AsyncClass {
    func doSomething(completionHandler: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        for _ in 0...5 {
            dispatchGroup.enter()

            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                let _ = (0...10000).map { $0 * 1000 }

                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }

        dispatchGroup.wait() // Doesn't work

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            completionHandler()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `dispatchGroup.wait()`? Even without that line, the `completionHandler()` should only call once all 6 asynchronous functions have left the group.

Comment: "I am looking for a way to make the calling thread wait for the dispatchGroup to finish working" That is exactly what a dispatch group _does_.

Comment: @DavidChopin Because I want the calling thread to wait, but that line is doing nothing indeed, I just copy pasted it somewhere from the internet but that line can be ignored.

Comment: @matt not really because the thread continues to execute code while the dispatchgroup is doing work. The calling thread must be blocked, I want to test to pass.

Comment: When omitting that line, it seems that you are using `DispatchGroup` successfully. Try removing it and get back to us if you are not getting the expected performance.

Comment: @DavidChopin ??? what do you mean? Did you read the question?

Comment: So the issue isn't with `DispatchGroup`'s notification, but rather you want to gum up the main thread while the asynchronous functions are executing? Doesn't that make use of the `DispatchGroup` and asynchronous functions altogether pointless?

Comment: @DavidChopin it’s a way to make sure all the threads are doing work (and getting the job done quicker in my case). I get your point, but when executing this code on a multithreaded envirnoment I guess it must be faster than doing all the work on 1 thread (main thread in this case)

Comment: "not really because the thread continues to execute code while the dispatchgroup is doing work. The calling thread must be blocked" No, the calling thread must _not_ be blocked. This is _asynchronous_. It is the opposite of "blocked". Your caller just continues on, and when the dispatch group is finished it calls the completion handler.

Comment: After all, _you_ are the one who said `DispatchQueue.global().async`. That's `async`. That means you do not wait. Of course you could say `sync` but if you do that, how can you ever be called back? `sync` and completion handlers are _opposites_.

Comment: @matt ok but this question is about how can I block the calling thread while doing async work

Comment: Also what's the goal here? Is to test something that's asynchronous? Then you're doing that wrong. There are calls to test asynchronous stuff and you are not using them.

Comment: @matt I just provided somr example code. The question is really how can I block the calling thread when doing async work.

Comment: And the answer is you can't. `async` is the _opposite_ of block.

Comment: @matt to speed things up when testing and have the calling side of the code not dealing with annoying closures and expectations

Comment: Also, you say "I want the calling thread (main) to be blocked." No, you don't ever want to block the main thread (or any thread, for that matter). As others have said, use dispatch groups, barriers, etc.

Comment: @JamesBucanek but I want to do it while testing

Comment: @J.Doe, for testing you can be forgiven ;)

Comment: The way to test something asynchronous is to use XCTestExpectation. Use it and stop doing artificial stuff that isn't the real goal.

Comment: @matt yes, the expectations are just really what I don’t want to repeat all the time, along with the closures. ‘Artificial stuff that isn’t the real goal’ what do you mean? Is Waiting for dispatching work artificial stuff?

Comment: In my opinion, yes. If it's asynchronous, pretending it _isn't_ asynchronous is failing to test what needs to be tested. In general, however, it might be even better to take a step back and ask whether what you are testing _is_ what needs to be tested. I find whenever I am tempted to test something asynchronous that I am testing the wrong thing. For example, there's no need to test networking; we _know_ what it does. It's your code's response that needs testing, and you can mock networking or use artificial data in order to test that.

Comment: “Now while testing, I can create expectations all the time and call this method with a closure, but that’s to verbose for me.” ... FWIW, I would not advise changing code in the project to make asynchronous methods run synchronously solely for the sake of testing (esp when you can accomplish this with expectations with [just three lines of code](https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/8989dade9c5bef9ac0db75040d65f747)).

Comment: @matt I used async work to to fill my local database with random data to do some performance tests. I dispatched the work to multiple queue's to speed things up, but I don't want the expectations and closures. Maybe I should have add that into my question more clear. However, I managed to do it spinlock way, which greatly increases speed and makes my test code much more clear. No more expectations and closures :).

Comment: @Rob No, that's a good point. Although in my case (filling the local database for performance testing/getting a feel of a real user (instead of an empty database)), I just want to add some data to my local database, which I want to do as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it spinlock-way (just sleep the thread in a while loop):

```
import XCTest

class DispatchGroupTestTests: XCTestCase {

    func testIets() {
        let clazz = AsyncClass()

        var isCalled = false

        clazz.doSomething {
            isCalled = true
        }

        XCTAssert(isCalled)
    }

}

class AsyncClass {
    func doSomething(completionHandler: () -> ()) {
        var isDone = false
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        for _ in 0...5 {
            dispatchGroup.enter()

            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                let _ = (0...1000000).map { $0 * 10000 }

                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .global()) {
            isDone = true
        }

        while !isDone {
            print("sleepy")
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
        }

        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

Now, the closure isn't needed anymore, and the expectations can be removed (although I don't have them in the provided examples, I can omit them in my 'real' testing code):

```
import XCTest

class DispatchGroupTestTests: XCTestCase {

    var called = false

    func testIets() {
        let clazz = AsyncClass()

        clazz.doSomething(called: &called)

        XCTAssert(called)
    }

}

class AsyncClass {
    func doSomething(called: inout Bool) {
        var isDone = false
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        for _ in 0...5 {
            dispatchGroup.enter()

            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                let _ = (0...1000000).map { $0 * 10000 }

                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .global()) {
            isDone = true
        }

        while !isDone {
            print("sleepy")
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
        }

        called = true
    }
}
```

So I did a performance test with the measure block and my expectations (not XCTestCase expectations) become fulfilled: it is quicker to dispatch work to other threads and block the calling thread in a spinlock, comparing to dispatch all the work to the calling thread (taking into account we don't want escaping blocks and we want everything sync, just for easy calling functions inside test methods). I literally just filled in random computations and this was the result:

```
import XCTest

let work: [() -> ()] = Array.init(repeating: { let _ = (0...1000000).map {  $0 * 213123 / 12323 }}, count: 10)

class DispatchGroupTestTests: XCTestCase {

    func testSync() {
        measure {
            for workToDo in work {
                workToDo()
            }
        }
    }

    func testIets() {
        let clazz = AsyncClass()

        measure {
            clazz.doSomething()
        }
    }

}

class AsyncClass {
    func doSomething() {
        var isDone = false
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        for workToDo in work {
            dispatchGroup.enter()

            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                workToDo()

                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .global()) {
            isDone = true
        }

        while !isDone {
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I still don't get what it is you're testing that needs async, sorry. If the idea is to test performance you would a real performance test. If the idea is to do the calculations you would just do them. I'm not grasping what you learn / test with this test.

Comment: @matt I got a database (CoreData). I want to do performance tests, like query results, on my database. I can only do any performance tests when I have actual data inside my database. To fill my database, I need to add data inside it. That's an expensive operation. I now have the ability to fill my database (AsyncClass.fillMyDatabase()) with a single method call without having any expectation/closure, while having the best speed when inserting new values inside my database (dispatching datafilling methods inside the fillMyDatabase method to other threads)

Comment: @matt I have never done performance tests on CoreData, so I am just filling random data inside my database. I am not sure if this is the way to go, simply because I don't have any experience. I just want to call my methods as easy as possible, maybe this is totally wrong. If you got any advice, that would be great :)

Comment: @matt the async is to dispatch work to other threads. If all the threads are working to fill data inside the database, that is quicker than just the main thread. Hmm, building the database outside the test and have a dependency on it would maybe better, because than I don't have all the hassle and the test is not flaky. I will try to find some resources on how to do it, never thought about it doing it that way, thanks!

Comment: Yes, if you construct the data as part of the test how do you know you got the data right? Who will test the tester?